# intellij Maven Project throwing java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalac

Intellij Maven Project set up tried and tested on Linux and Windows works fine, but trying to get it installed and running on one particular Windows machine 7 machine is throwing the below error:

Error:scalac: Error: com.sun.jna.Native.getNativeVersion()Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.jna.Native.getNativeVersion()Ljava/lang/String;

compilation using intellij works fine - running the intellij compiled class file with command line works fine.
It is only when you try to run it from intellij , it throws the following exception

Error:scalac: Error: com.sun.jna.Native.getNativeVersion()Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.jna.Native.getNativeVersion()Ljava/lang/String;

Tried download jna and jna platform jars directly from maven and adding , but to no avail.

Intellij compiles file ok, however run fails. Java JDK - 1.8, Scala version 2.11.12

Comment: did you verify the installed jna version on this machine is the same as on the others?
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679004/jna-unsatisfiedlinkerror-works-when-i-set-java-library-path-to-a-bogus-value

Comment: How do I check that, I downloaded the 5.4.0 jna and jna platform jars from Maven repo and added to the project libraries, but still no luck.